# How to change order of x axis using cenboxplot() function

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using the NADA package to create censored boxplots using the function `cenboxplot()`. I am wondering if there a way to change the ordering of the x axis. I know how to do this in several different ways with the `boxplot()` function, but cannot find a way to carry this over.

Comment: Can you provide some example code to show what you have already tried?

Comment: Also, could you please tag the language you are using?

Comment: For the boxplot() function, my code looks like this, which orders the x-axis the way I want it:
pH$Site<-factor(pH$Site, levels=c("Tank 1", "Tank 2", "Post CW"))
boxplot(pH$pH ~ pH$Site, las=1, main="pH", xlab="Sample Site", ylab="pH")

Because the cenboxplot() function requires a numeric vector, a logical vector that shows whether not the value is censored, and then a factor vector used for grouping ‘obs’ into subsets, I don't know how to reorder the x-axis. More here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NADA/versions/1.6-1/topics/cenboxplot