# Modify default cenboxplot (censored boxplot)

Tags: r, boxplot

I'd like to use the censored boxplot in the R package NADA but I want to reorder the X-axis.

```
library(NADA)
data(Golden)

#this should reorder the factor and change the x-axis but does not
Golden$DosageGroup <-factor(Golden$DosageGroup, levels=c("Low","High"))

cenboxplot(Golden$Blood, Golden$BloodCen, Golden$DosageGroup)
```

The help says the output is the default boxplot method but I cannot seem to get it to work.

[image]

PS - similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287311/how-to-change-order-of-x-axis-using-cenboxplot-function) but no answers were given

Comment: I had a look in the sourcecode of the `cenboxplot` function. It does not preserve order, because it modifies the factors. But as the function is quite small, one can derive an own version from it. R is Open Source ...

Comment: I am not that good at R to do anything like that, any suggestions?

Comment: @tpetzoldt : I hope I'm not "stepping on  any toes" by putting in a worked example here. (This didn't seem like a homework question.) Thanks for your many useful and instructive packages.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying a function in a loaded existing package consists of several steps:

1. get the code and store its environment

```
cenboxplot  # just typing the name of a function should bring up its code.
# this appears
function (obs, cen, group, log = TRUE, range = 0, ...) 
{
    if (log) 
        log = "y"
    else log = ""
    if (missing(group)) 
        ret = boxplot(cenros(obs, cen), log = log, range = range, 
                      ...)
    else {
        modeled = numeric()
        groups = character()
        for (i in levels(as.factor(group))) {
            mod = suppressWarnings(cenros(obs[group == i], cen[group == 
                                                                   i])$modeled)
            grp = rep(i, length(mod))
            modeled = c(modeled, mod)
            groups = c(groups, grp)
            
        }
        # problem with levels of the `groups` object
        boxplot(modeled ~ as.factor(groups), log = log, range = range, 
                ...)
        ret = data.frame(ros.model = modeled, group = groups)
    }
    abline(h = max(obs[cen]))
    invisible(ret)
}
<environment: 0x55a8acb2d708>
 cbp_env <- environment(cenboxplot)
```

2. figure where the function is deficient and make a copy ready to fix the problem:

It's because the constructed `groups` object doesn't inherit the levels from the group argument. When I'm looking at the code, I select the console output starting with the function name and ending just before the <environment ....> designation, and then paste that back to the console. I then put  an assignment arrow (`<-`)right after the function name.

3. Modify teh code before hitting enter (or copy it to an editor if it's goint to require major surgery.) After code is modified, assign new value to existing name (or a new name at your discretion)

The modification that succeeds: Put this line in just below the curley-brace that is the end of the for loop. (It's also just before the `boxplot` call:

```
    groups=factor(groups, levels=levels(group)) # adhere to user's intent
```

4. assign the same environment to the new version as the old version had:

```
    environment(cenboxplot) <- cbp_env  # which was stored above.
```

Now running your code yields:

[image]

There are other options to the `fname<-old_fname; environment(fname)<-environment(old_fname)` strategy. There is `reassignInPackage` in the R.utils package. And apparently you can do: `environment(censboxplot) <- asNamespace('NADA')`

Comment: Many thanks for working this out. A few comments: (1) @user918967 dont forget to assign the function to the function name (2) instead of fiddling with the environment, it is also possible to just rename the function, e.g. `cenplot2`, (3) The original code mixes `=`and `<-` for assignment, that should be made consistent by the original package author.

Comment: This is awesome.  However I am more puzzled by what `cenplot` does at this point.  I noticed that if the `max` of `cens` is higher than the maximum of the non censored date, the plot bombs.  Does `cenplot` calculate the IQR and median differently than regular boxplots?

Comment: 1) The code is available for your inspection and I believe you should be looking at the code for `cenros` and inspecting what it returns in the various situations you are creating, and 2) it sounds as though you might have found a bug in the code and should be using the `maintainer` function to determine who needs to be told about it, since you will at that point have a reproducible example to include with your email.